# Macro-like feature in emacs?

Tags: editing

If I need to remove everything in a parenthesis `{...}`, I do

1. Put the cursor on `{`
2. Click `C-space` (set mark)
3. Click `C-M-right` (go to the `}`)
4. Click `C-w` (remove selection)

How can I automatize these steps? How to do this macro-like action in emacs?

Comment: I am not familiar with the `C-M-=>` binding. Looks like it's specific to some major mode? In any case, `C-M-f` also does what you want in that step 3.

Comment: @KaushalModi But there's a shorter way: steps 2 and 3 can be replaced by `C-M-SPC` (`mark-sexp`).

Comment: Emacs would write `C-M-=>` as `<C-M-right>`. You can see Emacs's way of writing a key sequence by pressing `C-h k` (i.e. invoking `describe-key`) and then pressing the keys you are interested in.

Comment: Optionally, step 5: C-s { to take you to the next brace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Keyboard Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html#Keyboard-Macros) in the Emacs manual.

In summary: press `C-x (` to start recording a macro, `C-x )` to stop, `C-x e` to execute.

Comment: And keep typing e to invoke the macro multiple times in a row (in newer Emacsen).

Comment: @asjo: Yes, and if you want to execute the macro right after recording, you can skip `C-x )` and press `C-x e` *both* to finish recording and to execute it the first time.

Comment: Alternatively, press `F3` to start recording the macro, then `F4` to finish recording, and `F4` again to execute the macro.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use multiple-cursors as an alternative to use instead of
macros -- especially when you would only run the macro three or four
times and each one is viewable on the current page.

They're not quite as powerful as macros and there's some decent
performance overhead, but it can be a more intuitive solution.